# Popup won't appear when clicked inside a table button

Tags: javascript, php

Can anyone suggest some alternative solution for this problem.

> I've made a popup form which i use css and javascript to trigger the display to none or flex every time i click into a specific button which is great. But this method seems to not work on a table as you can see below i've done a simple query which i just fetch some of the essentials and included some buttons to use to trigger the popup form.

PHP/HTML CODE

```
                                <tbody>
                                    <?php
                                    $res=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT CONCAT(c.firstname, ' ', c.lastname) AS fullname, c.* FROM user_registration c");
                                    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
                                    {
                                            echo "<tr>";
                                            echo "<td>"; echo $row["id"]; echo "</td>";
                                            echo "<td>"; ?> <img src="<?php echo $row["image"]; ?>" height="100" width="100"> <?php echo "</td>";
                                            echo "<td>"; echo $row["fullname"]; echo "</td>";
                                            echo "<td>"; echo $row["username"]; echo "</td>";
                                            echo "<td>"; echo $row["id"]; echo "</td>";
                                            echo "<td>"; echo $row["id"]; echo "</td>";
                                            echo "<td>"; echo $row["id"]; echo "</td>";
                                            echo "<td>"; echo $row["id"]; echo "</td>";
                                            echo "<td>"; ?> <a href="#"><button class="btn btn-success" style="width: 100%">Accept</button></a><?php echo "</td>";
                                            echo "<td>"; ?> <a href="#" id="declineB"><button class="btn btn-danger" style="width: 100%">Decline</button></a><?php echo "</td>";
                                            echo "<td>"; ?> <a href="#"><button class="btn btn-success" style="width: 100%">View Message</button></a><?php echo "</td>";
                                            echo "</tr>";
                                    }
                                    ?> 
                                </tbody>
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE

```
document.getElementById("declineB").addEventListener("click", function(){
              document.querySelector(".popup3").style.display = "flex";
          })
          
          document.getElementById("closeDecB").addEventListener("click", function(){
              document.querySelector(".popup3").style.display = "none";
          })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have multiple elements with id `declineB`, `document.getElementById("declineB")` can actually only get the first element with id `declineB`. The effect you want will only appear when an element whose id is `declineB`. When click others, no click event will be triggered.

When you use css `class`, you can add click event to every html element of same `class`:

```
let elements = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('spacer'))
for (let element of elements) {
   element.addEventListener('click', ...)
}
```

Comment: I've try using class instead of id but it wont work. id works but it only triggers for the first row button in the table

Comment: how would we enable all the buttons to trigger the effect is it even possible?

Comment: I have updated the answer, you can iterate through every element with the same class, and then add click events to them

Comment: thank you ill try to use your code

Comment: let elements = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName(".declineB"))
      for (let element of elements) {
        element.addEventListener("click", function(){
            document.querySelector(".popup3").style.display = "flex";
        })
      }

Comment: i guess i did it wrong still won't trigger

Comment: @Hothorton Lose the `.` in `.declineB`. you're supposed to be specifying a class name, not a CSS selector.

Comment: @ADyson yeah i already did that but still wont budge

Comment: @Hothorton since you've now accepted this answer can I assume whatever your remaining problem was is now fixed?

Comment: @ADyson yes it is sry for the late reply been busy all day